# waitFor times out after calling renderHook()

Tags: reactjs, react-query, react-hooks-testing-library

I am trying to test a simple custom hook:

```js
export const getSearchResults = async (searchText: string) => {
  const { data } = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/search`, {
    params: {
      searchText,
      apiToken: API_KEY
    },
  });

  return data as SearchResponse;
};

export default function useFetchSearch(searchTerm: string) {
  return useQuery<SearchResponse>([ 'search', searchTerm ], () => getSearchResults(searchTerm));
}
```

First i tried to mock the API call with jest, then I tried it with nock as it says in the react-query docs (https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/testing).

My test looks the following:

```js
it('Displays card', async () => {
    const queryClient = new QueryClient({
      defaultOptions: {
        queries: {
          retry: false,
        },
      },
    });

    const wrapper = ({ children }: any) => (
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        {children}
      </QueryClientProvider>
    );

    const BASE_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;

    const expectation = nock(`${BASE_URL}`)
      .get('/search')
      .reply(200, {
        answer: 42
      });


    const { result, waitFor } = renderHook(() => useFetchSearch('test'), { wrapper });

    await waitFor(() => result.current.isSuccess, { interval: 100 });


    expect(result.current.data.answer).toEqual(42);
  });
```

the error I am getting is: Error: Timed out in waitFor after 1000ms.

My package.json is the following:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/dom": "7.21.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "^7.0.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "16.9.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.9.0",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.12",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "nock": "^13.1.1",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "16.9.0",
    "react-query": "^3.5.0",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3",
  },
```

Versions of react-test-renderer, react and react-dom are matching.

Any input is highly appriciated!

Comment: did you find solution for this?

Comment: add timeout instead of interval. Like below

`await waitFor(() => result.current.isSuccess, { timeout: 5000 });`

Comment: Also in jest.config.js `module.exports = {
  testTimeout: 50000
};`

Answer (score 1):

From your dependencies list, I would say that you are using `axios`, which is *not* what the examples in the react-query docs are using.

From the [nock documentation](https://github.com/nock/nock#how-does-it-work):

> Nock works by overriding Node's http.request function. Also, it overrides http.ClientRequest too to cover for modules that use it directly.

By using `axios`, you are likely not using `http.request` directly.

There is also a [common issues section](https://github.com/nock/nock#axios) in the docs about nock and axios:

> To use Nock with Axios, you may need to configure Axios to use the Node adapter as in the example below:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import nock from 'nock'
import test from 'ava' // You can use any test framework.

// If you are using jsdom, axios will default to using the XHR adapter which
// can't be intercepted by nock. So, configure axios to use the node adapter.
//
// References:
// https://github.com/nock/nock/issues/699#issuecomment-272708264
// https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/305
axios.defaults.adapter = require('axios/lib/adapters/http')
```

---

As an alternative, I can recommend using [mock-service-worker](https://mswjs.io/) to intercept network requests on a webworker layer. Advantages are that you can not only use these mocks for tests, but also for things like `storybook` or even during development.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the inputs. I found what the issue was:

I accidentally mocked my custom hook with `jest` before running my test. After removing `jest.mock('getSearchResults')`, it worked as expected.